# Runnable Jar from a JavaFX 8 project, JavaFX compenents are missing

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8

i created a Javafx project using JDK 8 and when i tried to export it to a runnable .jar file, i got surprised that it doesn't run using CMD, and gives the following error :

"Javafx compenents are missing"

while it works perfectly during the compiling time(using the IDE) when i accessed the .jar files, i found it has just .class files (that i made), and the needed library files that haven't been exported (i made sure to select the "extract need library files extract required libraries into generated jar" option in Eclipse), is there a reason behind of this? and a way to solve it? thanks in advance
Ps: i tried this using Eclipse and Intellij IDE

I just wanna mention once again that I'm using JDK 8 where it has JavaFX library inside of it.

Comment: Are you sure you are *running* it, not just building it, with Java 8? And is it Oracle Java 8 (as opposed to, for example, OpenJDK)?

Comment: you mean before exporting it ? no i make sure that i run it first, and it works as it should inside the IDE. Yeah i made sure it's Oracle 8, i downloaded from here : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html (Java SE Development Kit 8u301) i think it's the right one, isn't it ?

Comment: But which JDK are you using to *run the jar file*?  That’s what’s important.

Comment: What is the command you are using to run the jar file in the command line(I am guessing it is `java -jar <yourjarfile>`)?  What is the output of `java -version` in the command line?

Comment: I recommend using a more modern version of Java/JavaFX then Java 8, e.g. Java/JavaFX 16+.

Comment: my bad, i had JDK 16, the small size of the file made me think the problem is from the jar, and completely forgot to check my JDK version, thank you.

Comment: In fact i was using JavaFX 16, but exporting the project was like a nightmare, i didn't manage to do it whatever what, i read the best way is to use jpackager, it's just complicated, and i thought to downgrade to JDK 8, just to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [this](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)?

There are detailed instructions on how to configure your IDE to run JavaFX with newer OpenJDKs (which do not come with JFX components in it).

It also explains how to create a new JavaFX Maven project from archetype, with all the necessary plugins to easily build your application while including the minimal Java components for it (using jlink).

This will ensure that anybody using your application will have those components.